# Xamarin Forms - How to visually create a form

Tags: xamarin.forms

How in Xamarin Forms, can I visually layout and create a form. Like you do in WPF , WinForms etc.. etc... in VS and everyother IDE.  Do I alway have to hand-jam the XAML? Seems so absurd.

thanks in advance and have a great coding day

Comment: there is no visual designer - there is a XAML previewer.  You have to write the XAML by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Visual Designer, that has drag and drop functionality. You must code all views in either XAML or C#. (Preferably XAML).

The options you do have, is to view the XAML you are creating in real time, after you have typed it.

- [Xamarin Previewer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/) (still in preview, built in to Xamarin)
- [Xamarin Inspector](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-inspector-live-apps/) (if you have Visual Studio Enterprise)
- [UI Sleuth](https://xamarinhelp.com/uisleuth-visually-inspect-xamarin-forms-application/) (Like Xamarin Inspector, more geared towards Xamarin Forms, and free)
- [Gorilla Player](https://xamarinhelp.com/visual-designer-xamarin-forms/) (works by actually running on a real device or simulator, but you don't have to keep compiling your app to see changes).

Give it a few weeks of writing XAML and it gets much easier.

Comment: Hi.. thx .  That's ridiculous... you can do XAML visually, in VS with WPF. They need to do something.

Comment: Well its a bit trickier than WPF. How do you design something, where you can do XAML visually, for something that can be displayed on thousands of different device types and several platforms? It will look very different on each one.

Comment: you are correct... just thinking about initially adding the controls and a basic layout